# Why won't my iPhone 4 play through my bose sound dock anymore?

Tags: iphone, audio

It used to work, but now it doesn't. It now has iOS 5 on it. (I can't say for sure once iOS 5 went on it stopped working)

When I plug it into the docking station I hear the audio click, the green power light goes on the bose for a second, then it goes off then the phone charges.

If I go into Music and play anything, it appears as though it's playing though there is no sound coming from the sound-dock.

I can connect wirelessly to my Apple TV and it works, though then when playing on the TV, I connected it to the sound-dock and was able to select the "docking station" option (instead of Apple TV)

I've tried the phone on a cheap branded docking station and it works fine.

I've tried an iPod Touch in the sound-dock and it plays music fine.

I've restored the iPhone in case it was some glitch.
But still the problem persists. It charges, and appears to play, but no sound...

Its a SoundDock Series II, and both it and the phone have been powered off/reset to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might find [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4265/why-wont-my-ipod-touch-play-in-bose-sounddock-speakers-anymore) helpful, but then again, you might not.

Comment: If you haven't already, I think you should ask Bose support too.

Comment: Read through this question which may offer some troubleshooting steps to attempt. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83545/iphone-dock-connector-problems-with-and-without-accessories

Answer (score 2):

This is a software issue that Apple have not sorted out. I have an iPhone 4S and was prompted to update software on my phone. Since updating I have lost several important functions including the ability to dock the phone in my Bose speakers. Despite Apple support's advice to reinstall the phone, these issues remain.

Comment: Which iOS version precipitated these issues? Was it iOS 5, as the OP mentioned (though I believe the 4S shipped with iOS 5).

Answer (score 1):

There is probably pocket lint, dust, sweat (and God knows what else) caked up in the port. Take a toothpick and gently scrape all that bad stuff out. If this won't do the trick then off to Apple you go.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with that system but I do know that sometimes pins that connect to the iPhone or iPod may be damaged with regular use. In which I hope that's not the case. Also like "skipthepip" said, lit and dust could be the problem.

You might also have an issue with the Bose firmware. Since I'm not knowledgeable of the sound system I can't be sure if it has any firmware at all. My best guess is to ask Bose on getting it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I went to the apple store, they said it was some pins pushed back, making the iPhone think it was connected to a TV.  They couldn't fix it so it was replaced with a new iPhone 4 ($150.00 out of warranty), but it still did not work. I think it's a software issue.

Answer (score 0):

It must be a software issue.  Ever since I upgraded the software it doesn't work, however, when I plug in another phone that has not yet been updated there is no problem.

Comment: Interesting observation. I suppose it could be software for some people with this issue, but the majority of sound out problems on 30 pin connector devices I've seen were hardware. Thanks for reminding us it could also be software.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone 4 would not play music through the Bose dock so I used a 3.5mm stereo jack "from headphone" lead that plugged into the back of dock with a 3.5mm jack and bingo, I had sound through the Bose dock.

Answer (score 0):

I have multiple docs, chargers and headphones, and the problem that i see is PURELY intermittent.   NEVER happened until i updated to ios 7.04, and no .06.   The volume bar on siriusxm and youtube videos appears, and disappears, and if i'm lucky, it'll play after disconnecting from an alarm clock charger or power cable.   It MUST be software, it's all been cleaned and settings reset, also.

Answer (score 0):

It is a software problem. There are multiple threads regarding this issue based on the IOS update and it is happening on other docks not just Bose. So I would think it would be one hell of a coincidence that everyone's docks need to be cleaned or all have inop pins at the same time. I've also heard on another thread that Apple has been told of the problem but don't seem to care since they don't sell bose products anymore.

My iPhone 4 no longer works on my bose or my alarm clock docks the way it used to since I updated. It's obviously not a hardware issue. I read on another forum that buying a scosche adapter will allow it to work on your dock again. I haven't tried it yet but if you're interested I posted a link below.

http://www.scosche.com/car-audio/charging-adapter-for-ipod-iphone